# WebAPI: Retrieve GET parameter from Controller Constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Every call to my WebAPI may (or may not) contain the GET parameter

```
/api/SomeControllerFunction?loglevel=(someint)
```

From the function inside the controller I can initialize a LogCollector:

```
[HttpGet] 
SomeControllerFunction(int loglevel = 0)
{
    LogCollector logger = new LogCollector(loglevel)
}
```

To not repeat myself too often, I want to hide this in the class hierarchy by adding it into the constructor of a BaseController, from which all my controllers shall inherit:

```
public class BaseController: ApiController
{
    internal LogCollector Logger
    BaseController()
    {
        Logger = new LogCollector(loglevel);
    }
```

But how can I access a GET parameter from the constructor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constructor is invoked too early, you can't access the parameters from there. However, you can override the `Initialize` method and retrieve the GET parameters from the context:

```
protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
{
    foreach (var parameter in controllerContext.Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs())
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} = {1}", parameter.Key, parameter.Value));
    }

    base.Initialize(controllerContext);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using the constructor you could inject the `LogCollector` directly into the method. If you did want to use the constructor you should use a Di / IoC framework as that would be more appropriate.

In the example below you can use a custom `ActionFilterAttribute` instance which injects the Logger based the incoming (optional) log level. The log level is then defined in the route using a `RouteAttribute` on the action. The `RouteAttribute` also defines a default value for the log level so it is not required when calling that action.

**LogInjectorFilterAttribute.cs**

```
public class LogInjectorFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        const string key = "loglevel";
        if(actionContext.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            var loglevel = int.Parse(actionContext.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values[key].ToString());
            LogCollector logger = new LogCollector(loglevel);
            actionContext.ActionArguments["logger"] = logger;
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
    }
}
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/Home/Get/{loglevel:int=1}")]
[LogInjectorFilter]
public IHttpActionResult Get(LogCollector logger)
{
}
```